Every time I'm manually restarting my sonar local server, I'm getting SunCertPathBuilderException
I'm working on local Sonar, and every time I'm shutting it down (for change in configuration or plugins) it fails to start with this exception:
DEBUG web[][o.s.s.t.TelemetryDaemon] Error while checking SonarQube statistics: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Only after restart it's working again. any idea what can be done? I tried to look on many similar questions of SO but nothing helped
